# How to add JUnit 4 lib. to maven 1.0.2

Tags: maven, maven-1

So the problem is that I use maven 1.0.2 to build my program. I am aware that it is a bit obsolate but It was not my choice to use it. Still I would like to use JUnit 4 to test my app. I did not find anything that would solve my problem. Everything was about newer versions of maven. Can someone describe wheter it is possible and/or how to do that.

Comment: You need to add the JUnit to your dependencies...(I can't remember how this looks like for Maven 1.X).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to [this maven 1](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/reference/maven-model/3.0.2/maven.html) project descriptor on the syntax for maven 1.

The syntax is the same as that for maven 2/3 as per [this](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf) documentation.